# Chrome open tab containing url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a callback function that should search all tabs for a given URL, navigate to that tab if it's open and if it is not open it should open it.

I have the following query checking the tabs for the url

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: destination}, function (result) {
    //If it found no results then the page is not open
    if(result == null) {
        console.log(destination + " not found in tabs. Function will open Tab.")
        //Appropriate function...
    }
    //If it's open, the function will switch to the tab instead.
    else {
        //Use the tab ID of the first result
        var tabID = result[0].id;
        //Appropriate function using id to open tab
    }
```

The problem is that result is always null or undefined, and never returns an array (Even when destination == "http://*/*") I originally had if (result.length == 0) but it would give errors relating to the type

I've also tried using

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabID, {
    selected: true
});
```

to switch to the tab but this doesn't work. I thought it may be because I would need to place this in the background.js page, but I was unable to call it from this page.

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().myFunction();
```

does not work.

EDIT:
You mentioned permission causing an empty string. This is probably the answer, but I do have tabs set in permissions. These are my permissions in my manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "bookmarks",
    "browsingData",
    "identity",
    "topSites",
    "history"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a question about **chrome.tabs.query**.

This method takes an object as the first argument. A property called "url" can be set to a string using one of the following patterns. The result will be an array containing all tabs with urls matching the pattern.

*NOTE: Unless you have specified the "tabs" permission in your manifest, or a domain matching the returned url value, the url property of any returned TabObjects will be an empty string.*

Example queries:

***://*/*** will return all tabs

**http://*/*** will return all tabs with the http protocol

**http://www.google.com/*** will return all tabs with the http protocol and the domain www.google.com

While these patterns may remind you of regular expressions, they are not the same. The last asterisk in this query always means 0+ occurrences.

*Note, you cannot use the pattern *://*.google.com/* to search all subdomains of google.com.*

I will also note here that you can give an array of patterns for the url property to search.

Here is an example:

```
chrome.tabs.query( { "url":[ 

    "*://music.google.com/*", // copy this from manifest.json is better idea
    "*://video.google.com/*" 

] }, function( tabs ){ 

    if( tabs.length ){ /* tabs[ 0 ].url is blank depending on permissions */ }

} )
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but you mentioned lack of permissions causing an empty array? I did check my manifest when I first encountered the problem, but I put it in the edit for you to see for yourself. Is there something missing?

Comment: Lack of permissions will not cause an empty array. If the method returns any matches, the TabObjects that are returned may or may not contain an empty url string property based on if you have permissions set for the corresponding url. In other words, your permissions settings should not stop the query from retrieving an accurate query result.

Comment: Do you have any ideas what might be causing the problem?

It's not returning an array to me. I had copied the code sample from the API and it still did not work. I renamed *tabs* to *result* because it is called that in the API. I spent a good while on this before I decided to ask so I'm nearly certain that the problem resides in retrieving the array.

Comment: chrome.tabs.query( { "url":"\*://\*/\*" }, function( tabs ){ console.log(tabs)} ) should return at least one result

Comment: Just tried it. Output was \[ \]. Do you have any other ideas? I just tried with "active: true" and it gave me one object.

Comment: At this point I am out of ideas. Make sure you are using this function from your background page and that there is at least one window open with at least one tab set to a url.

Comment: ..and that you reloaded the extension completely after adding permissions